# Version clashes in python scikit-learn

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, scikit-learn

I had originally installed scikit-learn 0.16.1 through pip. But for using some latest features, I am tyring to install scikit-learn 0.17.0-dev version. I downloaded the zip from github and installed it by python setup.py install. Before this I uninstalled 0.16.1 by deleting the egg-info file from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ (pip uninstall wont work somehow). But now I have version clashes with 0.14.1.. I dont know how 0.14.1 is installed and taken as the default version. Any idea how to fix this ?
OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: you can find out very easily how 0.14.1 is installed by doing ``import sklearn; print(sklearn.__path__)`` and see if it might be a system package.
Btw, why do you want 0.17-dev?

Comment: use `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`?

Comment: I wanted it for the CalibratedClassifierCV to get better probability estimates... It is somehow not working in 0.16.1

Comment: @Siddarth no that just gets me 0.16.1 (latest stable release version)